# Azure Service Fabric Actor Reminder Registration Exception

Tags: azure, service, actor, azure-service-fabric, reminders

I'm using reminders in my Actors but have an issue when the first Actor attempts to register the reminder in the "OnActivateAsync", it throws an exception saying it's currently loading reminders please try again later.  The next actor successfully registers the reminder and proceeds to function as expected.  It looks like a timing thing but I did not see anything mentioned in documentation about async scenarios to avoid in relation to the registration process.

Comment: Not really solved as it seems a bit loose but I was calling a method on the Actor proxy right after I did a create.  I changed the code to delay my first Actor call and now it all works, still concerned but we'll see how it goes once the Actors start getting product scale work loads.  Still interested in a concreate answer.

Answer (score 0):

OnActivateAsync in called upon an instantiation of a specific actor instance - so only once. You may be getting into a situation of registering a callback on the actor instance that is not valid yet.

Sergiy
<><